# So, did Poincaré prove PBW or not?

Tags: lie-algebras, ho.history-overview, universal-algebra

This seems to be a question whose answer depends on whom you ask. Maybe we can come up with a final answer?

It is known that Poincaré, at least, invented something that can be called Poincaré-Birkhoff-Witt theorem (PBW theorem) in 1900. Okay, it was a version of the PBW theorem that required a basis of the Lie algebra, and it was formulated over $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb C$ only, but this is not unexpected of a 1900 discovery, and generalizing the statement is pretty straightforward from a modern perspective (generalizing the proofs, not so much).

What is unclear is whether Poincaré gave a correct *proof*. Poincaré's proof appears in two places: his paper

Henri Poincaré, *Sur les groupes continus*, Transactions of the Cambridge Philosophical Society, 18 (1900), pp. 220–255 = Œuvres de Henri Poincaré, vol., III, Paris: Gauthier-Villars (1934), pp. 173–212,

and the modern paper

[T. Ton-That, T.-D. Tran, *Poincaré's proof of the so-called Birkhoff-Witt theorem*, Rev. Histoire Math., 5 (1999), pp. 249-284, also arXiv:math/9908139](http://smf.emath.fr/Publications/RevueHistoireMath/5/pdf/smf_rhm_5_249-284.pdf).

I have no access to the former source, so all my knowledge of the proof comes from the latter.

Ton-That and Tran claim that Poincaré's proof was long misunderstood as wrong, while in truth it is a correct, if somewhat incomplete proof. The incompleteness manifests itself in the fact that a property of what Poincaré called "symmetric polynomials" (and what we nowadays call "symmetric tensors") was used but not proven. However, in my opinion this is not a flaw: This property (which appears as Theorem 3.3 in [the paper by Ton-That and Tran](http://smf.emath.fr/Publications/RevueHistoireMath/5/pdf/smf_rhm_5_249-284.pdf) and is proven there in an overly complicated, yet nice way) is simply the fact that the $k$-th symmetric power of a vector space $V$ over a field of characteristic $0$ is generated by $k$-th (symmetric) powers of elements of $V$. This fact is known nowadays and was known in 1900 (I think it lies at the heart of umbral calculus).

What I am not sure about is the actual proof of PBW. Since I don't have the original Poincaré source (nor, probably, the understanding of French required to read it), I am again drawing conclusions from the [Ton-That and Tran paper](http://smf.emath.fr/Publications/RevueHistoireMath/5/pdf/smf_rhm_5_249-284.pdf). My troubles lie within this paragraph on pages 277-278:

"The first four chains are of the form

$U_1 = XH_1,\ U'_1 = H'_1Z,\ U_2 = YH_2,\ U'_2 = H'_2T$,

where each chain $H_1$, $H'_1$, $H_2$, $H'_2$ is a closed chain of degree $p - 1$; therefore by induction, each is the head of an identically zero regular sum. It follows that $U_1$, $U'_1$, $U_2$, $U'_2$ are identically zero, and therefore each of them can be considered as the head of an identically zero regular sum of degree $p$."

**Question:** Why does "It follow[] that $U_1$, $U'_1$, $U_2$, $U'_2$ are identically zero"? This seems to be equivalent to $H_1 = H'_1 = H_2 = H'_2 = 0$, which I don't believe (the head of an identically zero regular sum isn't necessarily zero). The authors, though, are only using the weaker assertion that each of $U_1, U'_1, U_2, U'_2$ is the head of an
identically zero regular sum of degree $p$ - but this isn't obvious to me either.

What am I missing? Is this a mistake in Poincaré 1900? Or have the authors of [1](http://smf.emath.fr/Publications/RevueHistoireMath/5/pdf/smf_rhm_5_249-284.pdf) misrepresented Poincaré's argument? Has anybody else tried to decipher Poincaré's proof?

**PS.** I have asked more or less asked this question some months ago, but it was hidden in [another question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/61954) and did not receive any answer. Mailing the authors did not help either. So my last hope is a public discussion.

Comment: You mentioned that for fields of char 0, the elements of k-th symmetric power of a vector space is generated by symmetric powers of vectors. Beyond char 0, is it true for divided powers?

Comment: @Z.M: Maybe for a very restrictive definition of Lie algebras. Certainly not for abelian ones, since their universal envelopes are still their symmetric algebras.

Answer (score 17):

I don't know if Poincaré proved PBW in 1900, but Alfredo Capelli
did it for $\mathfrak{g}\mathfrak{l}_n$ ten years before.
Here is the link to [Capelli's paper](http://www.digizeitschriften.de/main/dms/img/?PPN=GDZPPN002252635) (in French).

Comment: Thanks, this is interesting. Is this the paper with the famed Capelli identities?

Comment: Yes it has these identities but I am not sure it is the first paper which contains them. There might be some earlier papers in Italian.

Comment: This is a remarkable paper: it describes the universal enveloping algebra (probably, for the first time) and gives an explicit description of its center (all in the case of $\mathfrak{gl}_n$). Also, Capelli's German paper with the original Capelli identity appeared earlier.